# OneSignal Android - function requires restful API key

Tags: android, json, push-notification, onesignal

good day everyone, i am currently developing an app on android that uses onesignal. i reached this problem where i don't know how to give the server the rest API key he requires. thank you very much in advance

Comment: Show your effort here.

Comment: this is how to send a post notification right? i am planing to send a post notification to the phone i am currently using by the way.

OneSignal.postNotification(new JSONObject("{'app_id': 'app_id here','contents': {'en':'Test Message'}, 'tags': [{'key':'user_id','relation':'=','value':'1'}]}"), new PNResponseHandler());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API Key is not usable from inside your app. This is because this key is like a password -- if a malicious user were to get their hands on it then they could send notifications to all other users as if they were you.

However, this Key is not required when sending messages through postNotification to individual users by their ID.

Comment: thank you very much, i figured out a way to do it using async http request and setting it as a header.